# URIError: Failed to decode param '%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'

Tags: manifest.json

I have a problem running application with webpack, I have this error:

```
URIError: Failed to decode param '/%PUBLIC_URL%/manifest.json'
    at decodeURIComponent (<anonymous>)
```

I tried to resolve the problem like resolved for favicon but it did not work for me

```
plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
            filename: "index.html",
            manifest: "./public/manifest.json"
        })
    ],
```

I want that index file can read the value of /%PUBLIC_URL%/. What I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

After configuring the webpack like this:

```
HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
    favicon: "./public/favicon.ico",
    filename: "index.html",
    manifest: "./public/manifest.json"
}).
```

Leave the manifest link like this in index.html:

```
<link rel = "manifest" href = "manifest.json" />
```

it worked for me.